# After Login I want a form to be submitted and redirect to the after login page

Tags: php, html, mysql

So I have written a very short code below I hope you guys could understand.

This is ***login.php*** code

```
<?php
$session_start();
$_SESSION['uname'] = $_POST['username'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root','','test');
$res = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT*FROM tb_test WHERE uid='$_SESSION[uname]' AND pass='$pass')";
if($res)
{
<form method="post" action="new_file.php">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your Name" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" placeholder="Submit" />
</form>
}
?>
```

Here is the ***new_file.php*** code

```
$session_start();
$name = $_POST['name']
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root','','test');
$res = mysqli_query($db,"INSERT INTO tb_test2 (name) VALUES ('$name');
if($res)
{
    header('location: login.php');
}
```

This code works perfectly fine. But after redirection to the login.php page, system doesn't recognize the previous $_POST['username'] and $_POST['password']. How do I solve this?

Comment: You could store them in `$_SESSION`...

Comment: You are storing `username` in `session` so you can use it.

Comment: **Warning!** _Never ever_ store passwords in plain text! Only store hashes created with [password_hash()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php). Then on login you can use [password_verify()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) to verify a password against a hash.

Comment: You are also _wide open_ to SQL injection attacks. Never trust user data so never inject it directly into your queries like that. Look up how to use [prepared statements with placeholders](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to make sure you're safe.

Comment: _"This code works perfectly fine"_ - If that code works, then you haven't copy/pasted your real code (without rewrites) since it contains syntax errors (you're missing the closing `"` and `)` in your `mysqli_query(....)`. Please make sure that the code you write here are a copy/paste of what your actual code looks like or we won't have a chance of knowing what's going on and you might introduce other issues (like the typo in this case).

Comment: Guys I have created a bypass.php page and stored userid and password in sessions and redirect to where I want and it worked it charm.

Comment: @e-logiXYoutube make sure clear your session after logout